# Push files to my Google Cloud Bucket from Android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

Our team is using Google Cloud Bucket to access the files.

Our bucket is open, so everybody can push any file that he wants.

We can also spectate the list of files in browser with link (you cannot actually because I should hide our secret bucket) https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/openbucket

But now I have to create app which has to upload photos to directory from bucket.

I found some info here: [How to upload a file in the google cloud storage using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808432/how-to-upload-a-file-in-the-google-cloud-storage-using-java)

But it is about creating buckets, special ids and keys.

But I don't have any keys. I'm just have an open Google Cloud Bucket and have to upload files to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you follow the example in the firebase. You can try the examples in the link below. [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Comment: I guess it is Firebase, but I need pure Google Cloud

Comment: This should work also for the google cloud. We are also using this in our project

Comment: It works with Google Cloud, but Firebase storage. It is free. I want to use Google Cloud Platform storage, it is actually paid

Comment: I think you can also access your google cloud storage with firebase sdk with appropriate permission.